# Are destination selection questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about destination selection on topic?

I can think of a few examples:-

- Which ski resort in Switzerland is best for a 7 day stay if we are novice skiiers?
- Which island in Thailand would be most approriate for a family interested in nature, local culture, budget of 1000 THB/night and wishing to avoid "night life" ?
- Where should I travel to see an Australian Rules Football game?

I'm assuming there would be some criteria for specificity, and the above could be expanded into something specific enough (probably not as-is).

([This meta question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/are-recommendation-questions-on-topic)  about recommendations is related, but different).

Comment: This one seems like it might have lots of answers as "North East USA" is a big place http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4417/looking-for-place-to-stay-with-pool-in-room-in-north-east-usa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they are on-topic as long as they are not subjective or open-ended etc. Use the [destinations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destinations) tag on such questions.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely make sure they're not subjective.  The 'Which ski resort is best' IS subjective.  Try to avoid that.